FIREFOX: INSTAGRAM embed url on Object not working
I am getting https embed links from the api to showcase inside the Object element. In Chrome it works just fine.
For Firefox, the iframe doesn't load. It's blank.
I've checked the console and network tabs for the possible error and find out that there's one error that is showing up in network tabs in dev tools.
NS_ERROR_DOM_CORP_FAILED

I have tried searching for the error on google but answers were vague and didn't work.
Some suggested to tweak firefox config for active media content display.
disabling content tracking -- Didn't work.
removed cache and logging in and out of the instagram account didn't work as well.
Not sure how to proceed.

<iframe src="https://www.instagram.com/p/C14fHSIP8ta/embed/"></iframe>, inserted into https://jsfiddle.net/9tjqz1ne/, works fine for me in Firefox, as soon as I disable tracking protection for jsfiddle.net.

The initiator of the request appears to be some script, in your screenshot - so maybe it has something to do with how exactly you are actually inserting this.

@CBroe Thanks for the response. I am using Object element to embed urls which has firefox support too. https://jsfiddle.net/a6ptjre1/. This doesn't work in firefox.
Interesting case is I've twitter and tiktok links to embed and they are working just fine.

Sure, object has basic support for embedding URLs - but that must not mean, that everything else will still work as intended. Especially in a case like this, where there is probably some cross-domain communication between the plugin and the parent page going on in the background.

do you set any CSP headers?
